# mvc sample code to read the id of the selected checkbox

Tags: asp.net-mvc

Is there any sample code of how to read the id of the selected checkbox in a view from a controller.

```
<% foreach (var item in Model.projects) { %>
     <tr><td><input type="checkbox" name="selectedObjects" value=" <%=item.ID %>"> 
    <%=item.Name %>

    <% } %>
```

What must be the code on the controller to get the ID of the selected checkboxes?

Answer (score 0):

Add a parameter named "selectedObjects" to your action method, and it will be populated by the selected values.

```
public ActionResult myPostAction(int[] selectedObjects)
{
     foreach (var value in selectedObjects)
     {

     }
}
```

Comment: I need to do the fllowing:
I the controller I need to 
1. Get the Id associated with each checkbox
2. Verify if the each of the checkbox is selected or not